# How to limit SQL result with recurrance

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2012

I have a SQL Table with recurring tasks.  For instance:

```
+------------------+----+--------------+
|       Task       | ID | RecurranceID |
+------------------+----+--------------+
| Take Out Garbage |  1 |            0 |
| Order Pizza      |  2 |            0 |
| Eat Breakfast    |  3 |            1 |
| Eat Breakfast    |  4 |            1 |
| Eat Breakfast    |  5 |            1 |
| Order Pizza      |  6 |            0 |
+------------------+----+--------------+
```

Anything with a RecurranceID of 0 is not a recurring task, but otherwise it is a recurring task.

How can I show all tasks with a limit of one row on a recurring task?

I would just like the resulting set to show:

```
+------------------+----+
|       Task       | ID |
+------------------+----+
| Take Out Garbage |  1 |
| Order Pizza      |  2 |
| Eat Breakfast    |  3 |
| Order Pizza      |  6 |
+------------------+----+
```

Using SQL Server 2012

Thank you!

Comment: Am I right in thinking that you want all non-recurring tasks returned, along with a single row for each recurring task (whether or not it shares names with a non-recurring task)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
;WITH MyCTE AS
(
    SELECT Task,
           ID,
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY TASK ORDER BY ID) AS rn
    FROM   Tasks
)
SELECT  *
FROM    MyCTE 
WHERE   rn = 1
```

It is not clear by your sample data, but you may need to also apply `RecurranceID` in the `PARTITION BY` clause, as bellow:

```
;WITH MyCTE AS
(
    SELECT Task,
           ID,
           RecurranceID,
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY TASK,RecurranceID  ORDER BY ID) AS rn
    FROM   Tasks
)
SELECT  *
FROM    MyCTE 
WHERE   rn = 1
                OR RecurranceID = 0
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I was a little unclear -- suppose all task descriptions are the same. I would like the list to show everything, but just a limit of 1 row where the recurrence ID is the same. Any ideas for that one?

Comment: @user3258767 Try my second script.

Comment: I have tried that, it lists all the Recurring tasks fine, but seems to limit regular tasks (ones with exact same Task Description).  All together there are 1098 rows in Tasks. There are 11 recurring tasks. These take up 263 of the 1098 rows. Table should result with 846 rows.  Script #1 yields me 736 rows, Script #2 yields me 738 rows, but I am looking for about 846.  Thank you so much

Comment: What identifies a unique task?  The only thing in your original post is the name itself, since you appear to only want one instance of `Eat Breakfast`. (Personally, I'm fine with Second Breakfast, but I guess that's something everyone has to decide for themself ... )

Comment: @user3258767 try now. I added RecurranceID to the output.

Answer (score 1):

You seem to want all non-recurring tasks returned, along with a single row for each recurring task (whether or not it shares names with a non-recurring task).  Are you looking for:

```
SELECT Task, ID
FROM RecurringTaskTable
WHERE RecurrenceID = 0

UNION ALL

SELECT Task, MIN(ID) AS ID
FROM RecurringTaskTable
WHERE RecurrenceID <> 0
GROUP BY Task
```

Comment: Updated this answer based on the additional information you posted ... let me know if this is correct.

Comment: Don't forget the GROUP BY

Comment: Thanks @siride!  Stupid copy/paste ... well okay, stupid me but it's easier to blame my keyboard.

Comment: Glad that it helps, and that you found an answer with good performance.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
select distinct task
     , DENSE_RANK () OVER (order by  task) dr
  from tasks
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope This Helps,

```
DECLARE  @test TABLE(Task VARCHAR(30),
                 ID INT,
                 RecurranceID INT)

INSERT INTO @test
VALUES('Take Out Garbage', '1', '0'),
     ('Order Pizza', '2', '0'),
     ('Eat Breakfast', '3', '1'),
     ('Eat Breakfast', '4', '1'),
     ('Eat Breakfast', '5', '1'),
     ('Order Pizza', '6', '0')


;WITH cte_OneofEach AS
(
   SELECT *,
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Task ORDER BY ID DESC) AS rn
   FROM @test
   WHERE RecurranceID = '1'
)
SELECT Task,ID,RecurranceID
FROM @test
WHERE RecurranceID = '0'
UNION
SELECT Task,ID,RecurranceID
FROM cte_OneofEach
WHERE rn = 1
```